# Git: which is the default configured remote for branch?

Tags: git, git-push, remote-branch

I have a remote bare repository `hub`. I work only in the `master` branch.
The last sentence of this error message below makes me wonder: How do I find out which is the *"default configured remote for your current branch"*? And how do I set it?

```
[myserver]~/progs $ git remote -v
hub     ~/sitehub/progs.git/ (fetch)
hub     ~/sitehub/progs.git/ (push)

[myserver]~/progs $ git branch -r
  hub/master

[myserver]~/progs $ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master

[myserver]~/progs $ git pull hub
You asked to pull from the remote 'hub', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Track the remote branch

You can specify the default remote repository for pushing and pulling using git-branch’s track option. You’d normally do this by specifying the --track option when creating your local master branch, but as it already exists we’ll just update the config manually like so:

Edit your `.git/config`

```
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

Now you can simply git push and git pull.

[[source](https://gist.github.com/569530)]

Comment: Wouldn't this also be set if the OP did `git pull hub master`?

Comment: @Ryan Bigg: Not automatically, or you would always screw up your config.

Comment: Why edit a config file when git commands exist for this very reason?

Comment: git branch --set-upstream local_branch remote/remote_branch (or when pushing, as detailed below)

Comment: @scragz: No way! the command approach guarantees your .gitconfig is left in a meaningful state.

Comment: My reason for using this approach is that I had a bunch of branches so it took me less time than applying a separate command for each branch.

Answer (score 267):

You can do it more simply, guaranteeing that your `.gitconfig` is left in a meaningful state:

## Using Git version v1.8.0 and above

`git push -u hub master` when pushing, or:
`git branch -u hub/master`

### OR

(This will set the remote for the *currently checked-out branch* to **`hub/master`**)
`git branch --set-upstream-to hub/master`

### OR

(This will set the remote for the branch named `branch_name` to **`hub/master`**)
`git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to hub/master`

### If you're using `v1.7.x` or earlier

you must use `--set-upstream`:
`git branch --set-upstream master hub/master`

Comment: For anyone wondering: the second command can be used for existing branches

Comment: @eric-hu as detailed in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking/4879224#4879224

Comment: The `set-upstream[-to]` command changes the **currently** configured remote.  The original poster asked about the **default** configured remote.  Surely that's not quite the same concept?

Comment: @StevePitchers Does git distinguish between them? Feel free to suggest an improvement / clarification, or, indeed your own answer.

Comment: Each branch has a **currently** configured remote, specifying which branch on that remote corresponds to the local branch.  The **default** configured remote determines which branch is pushed or pulled if you don't specify one explicitly.  This answer only sets the **current** one.  The accepted answer (editing by hand) also allows you to set the **default** one.  Does anyone know a command that avoids having to edit by hand?

Comment: `--set-upstream-to` made exactly the same changes in `.git/config` as @scragz suggested in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4847136/852866).

Comment: This does not explain how to find out which is the default one

Answer (score 38):

For the sake of completeness: the previous answers tell how to set the upstream branch, but not how to see it.

There are a few ways to do this:

`git branch -vv` shows that info for all branches. (formatted in blue in most terminals)

`cat .git/config` shows this also.

For reference:

- [how do I get git to show me which branches are tracking what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what)
- [What is this branch tracking (if anything) in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631706/)

Answer (score 4):

The programmatic version of the answer to this question is:

```
git branch --list "$(git branch --show-current)" "--format=%(upstream:remotename)"
```

This will output just the current branch's default remote name. The `--show-current` option will not work before Git version 2.22.0.

Comment: This doesn't output anything if your HEAD is in a detached state on a particular commit which is not associated with a branch name.

Answer (score 4):

### Git: which is the default configured remote for a branch?

##### "Get" commands

For a branch named `branch_name`, read it out with this:

```bash
git config branch.branch_name.remote
```

Examples:

```bash
# main branch
git config branch.main.remote
# master branch
git config branch.master.remote
```

Sample output:

```
origin
```

##### "Set" commands

*Change* the default remote for a branch like this:

```bash
# for branch "branch_name", change the default remote to "remote_name"
git config branch.branch_name.remote remote_name

# Examples:
# main -> origin
git config branch.main.remote origin
# main -> upstream
git config branch.main.remote upstream
```

There is no output when running the *set* commands just above.

##### See all remotes

See all of your remote names and their URLs with:

```bash
git remote -v
```

The `-v` means "verbose".

Example run and output:

```bash
wiki_copy_demo.wiki$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/wiki_copy_demo.wiki.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/wiki_copy_demo.wiki.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git (push)
```

### `git config` general details

You can programmatically read out any given branch's locally-stored remote-tracking remote name via `git config branch.branch_name.remote`.

Assume that you have a branch named `main` and its remote it tracks is set to `origin`. In that case, your `.git/config` file will contain this, among other things:

```bash
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

Running this:

```bash
git config branch.main.remote
```

...will therefore read out that configuration setting and return the value of `remote`, which is `origin`.

And running this:

```bash
git config branch.main.remote upstream
```

...will change the value of `remote` from `origin` (its previous value) to `upstream`.

You can use these patterns to programmatically read or write *any* git config variable, even ones you invent or make up yourself.

Example: this command: `git config --global blametool.editor subl` adds these lines to the bottom of your global `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[blametool]
    editor = subl
```

And you can read out that variable value, `subl`, with: `git config blametool.editor`.

That's how I set a blametool [for my `git blametool` script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66433627/4561887).

Answer (score 0):

This information depends on the remote, so different remote (on the same local clone) could have different default branches

```bash
$ git remote show origin | grep 'HEAD branch'  | cut -d' ' -f5
main
```

(Obviously repeat if necessary on any other remote `origin`, `upstream`, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

the command to get the effective push remote for the branch, e.g., master, is:

*git config branch.master.pushRemote || git config remote.pushDefault || git config branch.master.remote*

Here's why (from the "man git config" output):

***branch.name.remote*** [...] tells git fetch and git push which remote to fetch from/push to [...] [for push] may be overridden with **remote.pushDefault** (for all branches) [and] for the current branch [..] further overridden by **branch.name.pushRemote** [...]

For some reason, "man git push" only tells about branch.name.remote (even though it has the least precedence of the three) + erroneously states that if it is not set, push defaults to origin - it does not, it's just that when you clone a repo, branch.name.remote is set to origin, but if you remove this setting, git push will fail, even though you still have the origin remote

Comment: This question was already answered with a more useful answer.