# Moving GitHub repo to private repo on Raspberry Pi

Tags: git, github, ssh, raspberry-pi

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi. I finished installing and setting up SSH and Git on the Raspberry Pi. I am able to make connections and to transfer files using `ssh` and `scp` respectively.

I am using a 16 GB USB drive to store data which is mounted on `/media/data`.

I have several repositories on GitHub. I want to migrate those repositories to my Raspberry Pi such that each time I use `git push`, all commits are pushed to my Raspberry Pi.

For example, I own this repository on GitHub:

https://github.com/cfbaptista/PolyMath.jl

I push to this repository from my laptop by running:

```
$ cd /home/carlos/Workspace/PolyMath.jl/
$ git push
```

However, instead of pushing to GitHub I want to push to:

```
raspberrypi:/media/data/repos/git/PolyMath.jl
```

How do I perform the necessary changes?

P.S.: Momentarily, my Raspberry Pi is accessible only on my own local network. External access has not been set up yet.

Comment: The setup I would like to have eventually is: laptop > raspi > GitHub. I will be using GitHub only to reach out to the rest of the world. However when I am really in dev mode I only want to push to my raspi. So assume several pushes a day to my raspi and only one push to GitHub in 1 - 3 months.

Comment: @janos In case I want to abandon Github after pushing my code to Raspi, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a new remote which points to the new repo on your Raspberry Pi, see this article on [adding remotes](http://caiustheory.com/adding-a-remote-to-existing-git-repo).

E.g.

```
git remote add pi **url-to_new-repo**
git push pi master
```

The first command sets up a new remote `pi`, while the second pushes your `master` branch to `pi`.

If you want to make a branch push to a remote automatically, you can set it as a remote tracking branch. See this question for more details:

[How do I change the remote a git branch is tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking)

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Raspberry Pi and do

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/cfbaptista/PolyMath.jl polymath.git
```

This will create a bare repository containing a full "mirror clone" which would work exactly as the repository at github, just the repo URL will be different.

To "redirect" the local repository on your workstartion, use `git remote add ...` as suggested by ColinE.

The access itself to the repository is the trickiest part but it's out of the scope of this question — search SO for questions dealing with Git hosting.