# How not to affect the original cloned git repository

Tags: git

I have cloned a repository and in it there is a .git directory. What I'm worried is that if I commit, it will also commit to the original repository and that I don't want it to happen. Is there a way that I can do about it, by which it will not affect the original repository that I've cloned from.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
What I normally did to maintain my repository is as below:

```
cd /path/to/my/local_repo
git remote add origin my_repo_link
git push -u origin --all
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will only affect the original or remote repository if you use the `push` command.

Git is different from svn in that you have a complete local repo. You can `commit` to that repo all you want because it is a different repo. When you `push` you are asking your local repo to do an svn style `commit` of whatever you have changed in the local repo to the remote (original) repo.

If you want to clone from one repo and then push to a different remote repo you'll need to change the remote branch your local branch is pointed at.

[How do I change the remote a git branch is tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking)

Comment: I see..but I need to run the command push to maintain the git remotely(on the bitbucket, mine, not the original repo).

Comment: Am I correct if I run the 'push' command after changing the remote repo as in "git branch --set-upstream branch_name your_new_remote/branch_name"?

Comment: yes, I would try push a trivial edit like a comment as a test.

Answer (score 1):

If also worry about messing your local repository you can create a local branch:

```
git branch <my new branch>
git checkout <my new branch>
... <make all your changes>
git commit -a .
... <if your want to go back to your previous state>
git branch <your initial branch>
... < if you want to clean up>
git branch -d <my new branch>
```