# move HEAD in bitbucket (checkout another branch)

Tags: git, bitbucket, phonegap-build

I am pulling my code to Phonegap Build from Bitbucket using this :

https://myID:mypassd@bitbucket.org/boardlinedevs/boardline.git
but, altough I have done the following on my local machine

```
git checkout featureBranch1
```

Phonegap Build is sill pulling code from the branch `master` which means that bitbucket hasn't checkout the right branch.

How to chekcout to another branch in Bitbucket ?

Comment: Repositories on BitBucket are bare repository, which means there is no working directory that you can checkout to. But you can [change the upstream branch of your local branch with `git branch`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4878249/53114).

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is not possible, the only way is to change the so called "Main" branch of the bitbucket repo in the settings.
Too bad !