# Change the origin of git branch

Tags: git, git-remote

I have created branch this way:

```
git branch MyBranch origin/test
```

`test` was branch parallel to master. Now test is merged into master

How can i change the origin of `MyBranch` so it points to master

Comment: You want to simply change the remote tracked branch or you want to `git rebase`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the remote a git branch is tracking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no "origin" of a branch. A "branch" is just a label pointing at particular commit.

If you've made no commits to MyBranch, then you can delete and recreate it.

```
git branch -d MyBranch
git branch MyBranch master
```

If you have done work on MyBranch, then things are a little more complicated. Your situation is like this...

```
- A - B - C - D [master]
       \
        E - F [origin/test]
             \
              G - H [MyBranch]
```

`MyBranch` has commits G and H on top of `origin/test`. If you want to move `MyBranch` on top of `master` then you need to preserve the work in G and H. This can be done with a rebase.

```
git rebase --onto master origin/test MyBranch
```

This says to take the changes which are in `MyBranch` but not in `origin/test` (which is G and H) and put them on top of `master`. You get...

```
                G1 - H1 [MyBranch]
               /
- A - B - C - D [master]
       \
        E - F [origin/test]
             \
              G - H
```