# How to correct remote-branch-name vs local-branch-name mismatch

Tags: git

I created a new experimental branch on my local machine:

```
git checkout -b feature/random-experiments
```

Then made some changes to a few files and committed them:

```
git add .
git commit -m "1st cut - added cool new experimental feature"
git push
```

Later, we created a user story (U-123) and then decided to rename my branch to follow our naming standard.  I deleted the remote branch via stash's browser UI. Then:

```
git branch -m feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature
```

Then made some changes and committed:

```
git add .
git commit -m "clean up & refactor"
```

But now, when I do a git status

```
$ git status
On branch feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature
Your branch and 'origin/feature/random-experiments' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

It looks like my local branch is still pointing to the old remote branch. This is a problem because the old (remote) branch at origin :
1) had a different name
2) is no longer there as I deleted it.

What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [reset the upstream branch for your current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309):

```
git branch branch_name --set-upstream your_new_remote/branch_name
# or
git branch branch_name -u your_new_remote/branch_name
```

In your case:

```
git branch --unset-upstream 
git push --set-upstream origin feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature
# or
git push -u origin feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature
```

Make sure you are on the right local branch:

```
git switch feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature
```

And try to push from there.

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error message indicating that origin/feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature does not exist. I ended up doing a 2 step process : 1) git branch --unset-upstream and then 2) git push --set-upstream-to origin feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature.  (note the space between origin and feature.

Comment: --set-upstream-to has been renamed to --set-upstream, so it would look like this now
git push --set-upstream origin feature/U123-Add-Cool-New-Feature

Comment: @ShivaPrasad Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.