# How do I set which remote branch I'm pulling from?

Tags: git

If I make a new branch off of the master and want to be pulling updates from the remote master and not the remote new branch, how do I set that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the remote a git branch is tracking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
git branch branch_name -u your_new_remote/branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work too

`git checkout the_branch_you_want`