# Git branch change tracking in command line

Tags: git

git tool: Tower

a branch tracking:`origin`[image] and in commend line show :[image].next I change tracking in tower :`origin-fock`[image].in commend line:[image]

how to complete this operation at the command line with `git command`????

Answer (score 6):

```
Without deleting anything, using git v1.8.0 or later:
git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to your_new_remote/branch_name

Or you can use the -u switch:
git branch branch_name -u your_new_remote/branch_name

Using git up to v1.7.12:
git branch --set-upstream branch_name your_new_remote/branch_name
```

Referred from [How do I change the remote a git branch is tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking)

Also check
 [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)