# Github and Heroku terminal confusion (osX)

Tags: git, macos, heroku, github

I have a node server on Heroku and their terminal extension for git. How can I use both repositories separately? I have a repo on github that I want to use for a different project yet I cannot switch the push destination, it all goes to heroku master.

How do I change the branch? I've tried several ways already of setting a git origin branch and trying to push directly to it but it all still shows a heroku master.

`screenshots removed for privacy, see resolution details in comments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [change the remote tracking branch of your current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309) with:

```
git branch branch_name -u your_new_remote/branch_name
```

In your case:

```
git branch master -u origin/master
```

That would make `git status` and `git push` consider the remote `origin` instead of `heroku`.

Other solutions are possible:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
```

This assume that origin does exist.
If it does not (see `git remote -v` output), you can declare that new destination with:

```
git remote add origin /new/destination/url
```

If you want to completely replace an existing origin setting (for push and pull):

```
git remote set-url origin /new/destination/url
```

If you just want the push url

```
git remote set-url --push origin /new/destination/url
```

See "[Change the remote URL to your repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-the-remote-url-to-your-repository-794212774.html)".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Please see the new screenshot in the original post.

Comment: @Micard I have edited my answer for you to declare the remote origin.

Comment: please see another screenshot :)

Comment: Needed to pull from Heroku again before pushing but all good now! Thank you!