# How can you clone a branch from the original GitHub project to your fork?

Tags: git, github

I forked a GitHub project. I want to create a new branch, that is a clone of the original project's master branch (the master branch has new commits from when I last forked).

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe in your branch change the remote repo to the original and pull the latest changes `git pull`?...like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking#4879224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to [configure a remote for a the original repo](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/).

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
$ git fetch upstream
```

Now you can use any git command with any branch from the original repo.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull upstream master
```

Of course, you can checkout any other branch than master.

```
$ git checkout my-radical-new-feature
$ git pull upstream master
```

Typically I pull directly to my local master branch as shown here and then merge the local master into other branches where I am working.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull upstream master
$ git checkout my-radical-new-feature
$ git merge master
```

See [the GitHub docs](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Fetch from your upstream, checkout to that branch, then force push to that branch on your fork.

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout <target branch>
git push -f origin <target branch>
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Comment: This assumes that the OP already has an `upstream` remote configured.