# Switching tracking between git repositories

Tags: git

I just created a new remote repository then added, committed and pushed all local repository files to this new remote repository.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "all files added"
git push newRepo master
```

Before I did this I was pushing to another repository while leaving most files untracked as well as not committing changes to most files.

```
> git status

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Now my local repository is ahead of the oldRepo 2 commits and changes seem to be tracked between newRepo and the local repository. How can I revert back to tracking between the oldRepo and my local repo?

So there are 2 remote repositories: newRepo and oldRepo + my local repo
I need to track between local and oldRepo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a local branch track `remote/branch`, simply do

```
git branch -u remote/branch branch
```

Where `branch` defaults to checked out branch.

[--set-upstream-to](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--ultupstreamgt)

Comment: i did: git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to your_new_remote/branch_name. but git status hasn't reverted i think i need to pull the remote changes now

Comment: You used an incorrect syntax. It should be `git branch -u your_new_remote/branch_name branch_name`.

Comment: it works, from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Can you please specify exactly which branch is tracking which remote branch and say what you want to achieve? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: each repo just has a master branch. I need tracking to revert to being to as it was before I added and committed all my files to my local repo. So by tracking between my old remote repo shouldn't I be able to revert to whatever was committed and uncommitted?

Comment: If you want to revert to a point in history, just do a `git reset --hard <commit>`.

Comment: what if something is changed in my old remote repo, i want to make sure the local repo commits, file modifications etc are tracked to whatever was changed remotely

Comment: i guess i have to reset then pull?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the old repository, you can run `git remote remove origin` if origin is the name of the old repository. If you want to keep you old repository as a mirror of the new one, you can push the commit on origin: `git push origin master`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: there are 3 repositories, 2 remote and 1 local, I want to track between the local repo and the oldRepo (remote).

Comment: at the moment I think it is tracking between the local and newRepo (remote)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple steps:-

Open a command prompt or terminal and type

```
git config -e
```

You will see this kind of content

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = <new_repo>
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
        email = <local_user>
        name = Atul Agrawal

~                                                                                                                     
~
```

change the origin url to old url and save this file.You will have your old repository configured.