# Master branch is ahead of a deleted branch by 2 commits

Tags: git, github, version-control

It is kinda complicated situation

I am really new to github and its workflow concept. Yesterday, I started a project on local and pushed it to my remote. The default branch name was `railsAPI`. Then i tried to change the branch's name to `master`, however, I messed up at this part. The branch name in my local machine is changed, but the name of the branch stayed the same on GitHub. So i decided to create a new branch called `master`, set it as default branch and delete the `railsAPI` branch.

On GitHub, everything looks fine. However, on my local machine, when ever i type `git status`, the following message shows up:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/railsAPI' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I can still add, commit and push just fine.  but the fact that there exist a ghost branch on my local machine and every time I make a change, the master branch will be one more commit ahead of that ghost branch.

**what I have tried:** I tried to do git pull to synch with my Github, however, i got following message:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/railsAPI'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

I tried to search on SO, but i believe my situation is different from other similar questions since that branch has been deleted, so i don't think it is a duplicate question

**What I need help with** : How do I clean my local repo and what caused this strange behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have deleted the remote branch `railsAPI` on GitHub, but there is still a remote-tracking branch called `origin/railsApi` in your local repo, and your local `master`branch is still set to track it.

You need to [change the branch that your local `master` branch is tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-do-i-change-the-remote-a-git-branch-is-tracking) to be the `master` branch on GitHub:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

You may also want to delete the remote-tracking branch left behind in your repo:

```
git branch -d -r origin/RailsApi
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i wonder, after i changed the name of my local branch, what should do I so that the remote branch will also change accordingly?

Comment: @aDev I'm not sure I understand the question... Could you clarify?