# How can I fix git local branch tracking issue?

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

Hi! recently I had a issue with my local branch ("new-design"), where from months ago it was tracking its remote branch (origin/new-design) perfectly.  In this week I realize that my commits wasn't reflecting in this remote branch, also, it changed unexpectly to master remote branch (origin/master).

From this: **local/new-design - origin/new-design** to this: **local/new-design - origin/master**

Tracking the repository history I had never opened a pull-request (this whould not change traching branch references) neither changed mannualy this references.

Any ideas about what happened here? And more important, what is the best method (rebate-onto, compare, etc) to move all commits done in master to new-design branch?

Comment: Always git push <remote> <branch> or read about upstream in the git doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `git branch -avv` can show you which branch is tracking which.

Second, you can [change your remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309) with:

```
git branch new-design -u origin/new-design
```

Comment: Before try this, what about those changes I have already commited there? They will dissapear or remain in local branch?

Comment: No, it only set the link with a remote tracking branch, and has no bearing on the existing commits.

Comment: Great!!!, @VonC, as you said, it perfectly re-track the branch and nothing has lost. Thanks bro!.