# git remote tracking branch return "requested upstream branch does not exist"

Tags: git

I've git config like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
   url = git@bitbucket.org:archie/learn-express.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
   remote = origin     <==== 
   merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "znotanto"]
   url = https://archie@bitbucket.org/znotanto/learn-express.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/znotanto/*
```

I wanna change the part that I show with arrow to `znotanto`. I've tried `git branch master --set-upstream-to znotanto/master` from [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-to-change-the-remote-a-branch-is-tracking) but give me error

**error: the requested upstream branch 'znotanto/master' does not exist**

Answer (score 1):

Does the repository copy over at `znotanto` (`https://archie@bitbucket.org/znotanto/learn-express.git`) actually have a branch named `master` yet?

If so, use:

```
git fetch znotano
```

to get your Git to learn about it.  This will have your Git create your remote-tracking name `znotanto/master`, after which you will be able to set `znotanto/master` as the upstream of any of your branches.

If not, you need to first *create* the name `master` in the Git repository at `znotanto`, so that your Git will see it so that your Git will create your remote-tracking name `znotanto/master`.  So in this case, first create that branch there—exactly how is not important—and *then* run `git fetch znotanto`.