# Github - no file changes but many commits when comparing branches

Tags: git, github

I'm comparing dev branch in my fork with the dev branch in the upstream. It shows diff of 30 commits, but 0 files changes. All the commits appear in the diff are old commits which already merged to the upstream (mainly type of "Merge branch dev.."). This makes an issue where each PR shows those many old commits. Tried rebase and still showing the same diff.

Why this happens? Can you please assist how to resolve? We're using Github for Enterprise so can't attach a url that show the diffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why this happens?

Possibly because you might have done PR (Pull Requests) from yourFork(origin)/dev and upstream/dev, which is not a good practice.
You would normally do a PR from a dedicated branch (`myfix`) to `upstream/dev`. And then simply reset your own `dev` to `upstream/dev`, in order to have in your fork an exact image of `upstream/dev`, and:

- make new `fix`/`feature` branches for future PRs,
- rebase existing `fix`/`feature` branches on top of `dev` in order to facilitate future PRs.

If everything is committed or stashed locally, I would:

- create a dedicate branch (`myfix` or `myfeature`) right where my local `dev` is (assuming I was developing the next PR directly on `dev`)
- reset dev to upstream dev

That is:

```sh
git switch dev
git branch myfix
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/dev
git push --force
git switch myfix
# resume working
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I supposed we should "git push" after the reset to make the fork updated?

Comment: @Seffy yes, a force push. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: from now on I should update my fork using "git pull upstream dev" and "git push", will that make my dev branch aligned as expected?

Comment: @Seffy Yes. I would actually [change the upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/6309) for `dev`: `git branch dev -u upstream/dev` and `git remote set-url --push upstream url/of/fork`, that way a simple `git pull` is enough: it will pull from the right remote for `dev` and still push to your fork.