# Git unable to push to branch master even master branch is available?

Tags: github

I am unable to push to git master, even master branch is there. I have tried  `git push -u origin master` .

```
git --version
git version 2.32.0.windows.2
```

The commands executed .

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin http://url
git push -u origin main   **//master is not working**
```

[image]

main branch is working

[image]

I have created a remote repository say **git_example** and then in the same name created a local repository(**git_example**) and tried to push it to remote.

```
D:\WORKSPACE\REACT\ems-backend-springboot>git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/subhashisz/ems-backend-boot.git'

D:\WORKSPACE\REACT\ems-backend-springboot>git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 67, done.
Counting objects: 100% (67/67), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Writing objects: 100% (67/67), 68.39 KiB | 1.27 MiB/s, done.
Total 67 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'main' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/subhashisz/ems-backend-boot/pull/new/main
remote:
To https://github.com/subhashisz/ems-backend-boot.git
 * [new branch]      main -> main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

Comment: I faced the problem because there is a README.md file present in the repo  :)

Answer (score 1):

You already set your "main" branch as main via the command:

```
git branch -M main
```

and set any following "git push" to push to the main branch via the command:

```
git push -u origin main
```

so in order to push to master, you need to execute:

```
git push origin master
```

also in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-to-change-the-remote-a-branch-is-tracking) you can find how to change your upstream branch if already set:

```
git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to origin/branch_name
```