# Git Checkout Vs Git Checkout -B with upstream repo

Tags: git, github

Say I forked the Upstream. My remote repo has a model-package branch.

when I do ***git fetch upstream model-package***. It fetches from the upstream to the local repo right?
What happens when I do ***git checkout model-package***? Does it point to the remote model-package branch?

What happens when I do ***git checkout -B model-package upstream/model-package***? Does it creates a new model-package branch on the local repo that keeps on sync with the upstream/model-package branch? If it's so will it replace the previous model-package branch?

I tested practically, but quite did not get it. Can someone clarify this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Md Samiul Alim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69998427/1256452) is fine, and also has the virtue of being short—many of mine don't as I won't take the time required to make them short—but if branch names aren't ["clicking"](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/click-with-someone) for you, the reason might be as simple as this: **Branch names, in Git, don't matter.**

We—as in people, documentation, etc.—often talk about Git commits as being "on a branch".  This isn't *wrong*.  The problem is that it isn't *right* either.  The very notion that some commit is "on" some branch is mushy, muddle-headed, and misleading.  Commits in Git are their own thing: **Commits exist independently of branches.**  A commit either is there, in the repository, or it isn't and therefore it does not exist.  **Commits are Git's *raison d'être***.  In an important sense, nothing else matters: only the commits matter.  Git is all about the commits.

#### Commits are ...

Git's commits are:

- *Frozen for all time.*  This is an inherent property of all of Git's internal objects, though this post won't explain why.  The thing to remember here is that once we make some commit, *not even Git can change it*.  The new, unique commit we just made is stuck the way we made it, forever.  (If it's *bad*, we can just let Git eventually "forget it", though again I won't go into any detail here.)
- *Numbered*.  Every commit has a unique number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), which Git calls a *hash ID* or *object ID*.  These things are huge, ugly, and generally impossible for humans to remember: <sub><sup>[`5a73c6bdc717127c2da99f57bc630c4efd8aed02`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a73c6bdc717127c2da99f57bc630c4efd8aed02)</sup></sub> for example.  Git *needs* the commit number to do anything with the commit, including simply to *find* it.
- *Snapshots*.  Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file, as of the form it had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.  The files inside any one commit are in a special form, readable only by Git itself and literally unwritable by anyone or anything (including Git itself).  They're compressed and de-duplicated, so when most commits mostly re-use most of the files from other commits, the commits take almost no *space* because they're not actually storing the files again.
- *Nodes in a graph*.  This requires more explanation, but the way Git handles this is that besides storing a snapshot, each commit also stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  That includes who made the commit and when.  It includes a log message; you get to supply this log message at the time you run `git commit`, if you're the one making the commit.  And, it includes the raw commit numbers—the hash IDs—of a list of *earlier commits*.

Most commits store, in their metadata, the raw hash ID of exactly one previous commit, which we call the *parent* of the commit.  That means that this commit itself remembers which (single) commit comes *just before it*.  We say that a commit *points to* its parent, and if we want to *draw* this, we can do it like this:

```
            <-H
```

Here, `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  It has an arrow coming out of it, pointing backwards to its parent commit:

```
        <-G <-H
```

The parent of `H` is `G`.  But `G` is a commit too, so it has another arrow coming out of it, pointing to its parent `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This repeats all the way back to the very first commit ever: commit `A` in our example repository here, which therefore has just eight commits in it, `A` through `H`.  This first commit *doesn't* point back, because it can't: its list of previous commits is empty.  That gives programs like `git log`, which work by chasing along the backwards-pointing arrows, permission to quit, so that they don't have to run forever.

**This nodes in a graph thing, or pointing backwards, is what makes most of Git work.**  All Git needs to read *every* commit in this simple case is for us to supply *to* Git the raw hash ID of the *last* commit, `H`.  But where will we keep this last commit hash ID?  Do we jot it down in the office whiteboard?  Do we write it down on a slip of paper and carry that around in our pockets?  We could do either of these, but that's pretty painful.  We have a *computer:* why don't we have the *computer* store the hash ID, perhaps in a file or something?

#### Branch and other names help us, and Git, find the commits

This is where branch names come in.  A *branch name* is just an entry in some file—in a database of some sort—in which we have Git store the hash ID of the *latest commit*.

More precisely, the branch name stores the hash ID of the *latest commit that is to be considered "on" that branch*.  Let's take note of several things here:

- **Branch names owe their existence to commits.**  It's not the other way around.  The branch name *cannot exist* without a commit.  The name *points to* a commit.  The commit has to exist!
- **The hash ID stored in a branch name is not permanent.**  We can *update* the name.  Like erasing the hash ID written on a whiteboard, we can replace the hash ID stored in the name.  This means branch names "move around", at least when we draw them like I do (you'll see this in a moment).
- **If we already have a hash ID, we don't need a branch name.**  If we find some commit's hash ID somehow—regardless of *how*—we can give that to Git directly and not bother with a branch name.
- **More than one branch name can hold the same hash ID**.

Let me illustrate the last part, and then show branch names moving around.  We'll start with our simple chain ending at `H`.  For laziness and ASCII-art-on-Stack Overflow purposes, I will stop drawing the arrows between commits, but remember that like all parts of any commit, they're frozen for all time, pointing backwards from child to parent:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Here, all I did was add a branch name, `main`, *pointing to* (storing the hash ID of) commit `H`.  This means commit `H` is the latest commit on branch `main`.  Git can *find* every other commit by starting here and working backwards, so *all* the commits are on `main`, but `main` *points to* `H`.  (We call this the *tip commit* of branch `main`.)

Now let's add a new branch name, `br1`, and make it point to `H` too:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1, main
```

This means `H` is now the latest commit on branch `br1`.  But it's the latest commit on branch `main`.  So which branch is it on?  **Git's answer is that it, and all the other commits too, are on *both branches* at the same time.**  By creating a new branch name, we changed which branches the commits are on.  That's entirely normal in Git!  Nothing *about* the commits has actually *changed*, it's just that now we have two *names* by which to *find them*.

Now that we *do* have two names, we need a way to remember *which name we are using*.  Git does that for us by attaching a special name, `HEAD`—this isn't a *branch* name and it's very much a reserved name in Git<sup>1</sup>—to one of the branch names, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1, main (HEAD)
```

Here, we're "on" branch `main`—the `git status` command will say `on branch main`—and hence we're using commit `H`.  If we run:

```
git switch br1        # or git checkout br1
```

we get:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), main
```

We're now "on" `br1`, but still using *commit* `H`, so *nothing else changes*.  Git says to itself: *Oh, you'd like to switch branches to `br1`, hm, that's the same commit we're using now, I don't really need to do anything except update the `HEAD`, so I'll do that and say all done.*

---

<sup>1</sup>That's why you should be careful to spell it in all uppercase, even if lowercase sometimes works.  Or use `@`, which is a one-character synonym for `HEAD`.  The mechanism Git currently uses to store the branch name *in* `HEAD` is to have a file, `.git/HEAD`.  If this file ever goes missing, Git stops believing that the Git repository *is* a repository.  If your computer ever crashes, because the `HEAD` file tends to be active, your computer might decide it's been corrupted and remove it.  Sometimes this makes Git declare that your repository isn't a repository any more.  Putting a `HEAD` file back in makes Git happy and your repository works again.  That's a handy trick to know, if your computer crashes a lot.

---

#### Making new commits

You have already made some new commits, probably, so you know that you do this by modifying some files and running `git add` and then `git commit`.  There is a lot more to know here—a whole bunch of secret stuff that a lot of Git tutorials don't cover very well—but let's jump right to the end now and look at what happens *when* you run `git commit`.

You're already "on" some branch:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), main
```

You modified files and used `git add` and now you run:

```
git commit
```

Git gathers up a commit log message from you—this is going into the *new* commit forever, so it's a good idea to write up a nice one, though there are ways to recover from mistakes here—and gets your name and email address from your `user.name` and `user.email` settings, in your personal Git configuration.<sup>2</sup>  Git gets the rest of the commit metadata—such as the date-and-time stamp—on its own.  Among that rest-of-the-metadata, Git finds the raw hash ID of the *current commit* `H`, and puts that into the metadata for the new commit, too.

Git makes the *snapshot* for the new commit from whatever is in Git's *index* [aka](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aka) *staging area*.  This is why you had to run `git add`.  We won't go into the details here, but the index / staging-area content is already in the right *format* for a commit, so this part goes very fast.<sup>3</sup>  Git combines the snapshot and the assembled metadata and writes out a new commit, which gets a new, unique, big ugly hash ID, but we'll just call this `I`.  New commit `I` thus points back to existing commit `H`:

```
             I
            /
...--F--G--H
```

and now Git performs its clever trick: Git *writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name*.  Since `HEAD` is attached to `br1`, this makes `br1` point to `I` instead of `H`:

```
             I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

You now have a new commit on your new branch.  Commit `I` is now the *latest* commit on `br1`.  Commit `H` continues to be on both branches—as are all the previous commits—but new commit `I` is *only* on `br1`, and is the tip commit *of* `br1` now.

If we make a second new commit here we get:

```
             I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

The name `br1` has moved to point to `J` now, and now there are two commits that are only on `br1`.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is why you have to set `user.name` and `user.email`.  On some systems, Git is configured to *guess* these settings if necessary, so if you didn't have to set them, and `git commit` does not error out with a message telling you to set them, it's using the guessing system.  Did it guess right?  If not, configure these.

<sup>3</sup>I've seen people complain about how slow this part is.  They don't know "slow".  (Insert [four Yorkshiremen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue7wM0QC5LE) comedy sketch here.)  Seriously, pre-Git version control systems sometimes gave you time here to go out for lunch.

---

#### Cloning: we don't have to use *branch* names

Suppose some *other Git repository* has this:

```
             I--J   <-- br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We now use `git clone` to *copy that repository's commits*.

The `git clone` command:

1. makes a new, empty directory (or folder if you prefer that term) and enters the new directory;
2. creates a new, empty Git repository—one with no commits and no branches—here and does the rest of its Git operations here;
3. adds what Git calls a *remote*, `origin`, to store the URL of some existing Git repository;
4. runs any extra `git config` operations that might be required (we didn't need any here);
5. runs `git fetch` to connect to the other Git repository and download *all of its commits*; and
6. creates, in this new repository, *one* branch and checks that one out.

The one branch that `git clone` creates in step 6 is the branch you name on the command line:

```
git clone -b br1 <url>
```

will have your Git create the name `br1`, instead of the name `main`.  If you *don't* give a `-b` argument, your Git asks their Git which name they recommend.  They recommend whichever name *their* `HEAD` is attached to, so your Git will make a `main`.

You can tell your Git *not* to create and check out any branch name, using `--no-checkout`.  Then you have *no branches at all*.  You don't actually *need* any branches yet—you only need them when you start creating commits—but it "feels weird" to use a branchless Git repository.  Still, let's draw the branchless repository you would get this way:

```
             I--J   <-- origin/br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/main
```

Note how your Git has taken their *branch* names, `br1` and `main`, and *changed them*.  These are your own Git's *remote-tracking names*.  They remember the *branch* names the other Git repository had, as of the time you ran `git fetch`.  That was via `git clone` in this case, but a later `git fetch` will get any *new* commits *from them*, and then update your remote-tracking names.

So, in Git, *cloning* a repository means *get all their commits and none of their branches*.  The last step—step 6—of a normal clone, though, is a `git checkout`, and in the right circumstances—including this one—`git checkout` will *make* a branch name.

When clone or checkout makes a branch name like this, it uses the remote-tracking name that your Git set up to find the right commit, and makes a branch name in *your* repository that points to that commit.  So if we let `git clone` create `main`, we get:

```
             I--J   <-- origin/br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

Whichever branch we have our Git create here, that's the branch we're on, so if we choose `br1` instead, we get:

```
             I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD), origin/br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/main
```

#### Guesswork branch creation

Let's say we cloned with `-b br1` above.  If we run `git checkout main`, Git will search our branches and *not find a `main`*.  The same happens with `git switch main` (the newer Git command).

Instead of just summarily spitting out an error message, though, Git now uses what used to be called *DWIM* (Do What I Mean) and is now controlled by `--guess` or `--no-guess`.  Git will look through our *remote-tracking names*.  If one of them looks right, Git will assume we meant:

- using the remote-tracking name's commit,
- make a new branch name, and
- switch to that branch

which will, in our case, do this:

```
             I--J   <-- br1, origin/br1
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

and now we have the same two branch names they had, pointing to the same two commits.  We're now "on" commit `H` via branch `main`.  We're ready to make *new* commits on either of our branches.

#### GitHub "fork"

The *fork* button on GitHub is really a special case of cloning but with added features.

If we run `git clone` to clone some existing GitHub repository on our laptops, we get a new repository on our laptop with *no branches* (until we create one, maybe as the last step of the clone) but all the commits.  We get a name `origin` that remembers the URL, too.

If we use the GitHub <kbd>FORK</kbd> button on a web page, though, GitHub will:

- clone the repository *on GitHub* for us, into a "fork" in our GitHub account;
- link the two repositories together, so that we can make "pull requests"—also a GitHub feature; and
- cleverly copy *all their branch names* into our GitHub fork.

That last step is very different from `git clone`.  They do it because they don't make *remote-tracking names* in the fork: they only make *branch* names instead.

The linking-together is in some ways vaguely similar to the way our Git saves a URL under the name `origin`.  However, the linking-together on GitHub lets *GitHub* save a lot of disk space: they can and do literally share underlying files over on GitHub.  That's not something that you need to care about, and when you clone a repository locally, you *can't* use their (GitHub's) disk drives.  But it drives a lot of the decisions GitHub make, in terms of why they do things a little differently from Git-on-your-laptop.

#### This brings us back to your original questions

> when I do `git fetch upstream model-package`. It fetches from the upstream to the local repo right?

This `git fetch` is a limited form of `git fetch upstream`.  The unlimited one:

- has your Git call up their Git via the remote name `origin` and the URL stored there;
- has your Git list out *all* their branches and commit hash IDs; and
- has your Git get *any* new commits they have, that you don't, and then update *all* your remote-tracking names.

The limited one does the same thing but skips updating all but `upstream/model-package`, and doesn't bother getting commits that won't add to your `upstream/model-package`.  This may go slightly faster now, at the cost of going slightly slower tomorrow if/when you want other commits and/or remote-tracking names updated.

> What happens when I do git checkout model-package? Does it point to the remote model-package branch?

No, or not quite:

- If you have a branch name `model-package`, your local Git picks out that name and attaches `HEAD` there, and checks out that commit.
- If you don't have `model-package`, your Git uses `--guess`.  If there's both an `origin/model-package` *and* an `upstream/model-package`, your Git says that it has too many choices here and gives up.  If there's only one matching name, your Git creates a new branch name, as below for `-b` (lowercase).

> What happens when I do `git checkout -B model-package upstream/model-package`? Does it creates a new model-package branch on the local repo that keeps on sync with the upstream/model-package branch?

With a lowercase `-b`, your Git:

- finds `upstream/model-package` (the remote-tracking name);
- creates a *new* `model-package` pointing to the same commit, and checks that one out.

If your Git *can't* create a *new* branch `model-package`—because there's an existing one in the way—your Git gives you an error here.

If not, you now have a `model-package`.  Git sets the *upstream*—that's a different term than `upstream`, though unfortunately horribly similar *looking*—for the new branch to `origin/model-package`.  The *upstream setting* of a branch is just a loose connection for various operations; see [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452) and [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/1256452)

With an *uppercase* `-B` option, the "error out" variant doesn't happen.  Git says: *Oh I see you already have a `model-package`... I should complain, but, uppercase B, I guess you want me to delete that one and create a new one in its place*, more or less.  So the old `model-package` name, which selected some particular commit, is simply *overwritten*.  The new `model-package` name, which occupies the same database slot as the old one, now points to the same commit as `upstream/model-package`.

The precise details of what happens when *resetting an existing `model-package` branch* are a little tricky.  The documentation does not go into complete detail.  In particular, if you're *on* that branch right now, does it error out?  I'd have to experiment to see.

Answer (score 1):

**Git Checkout Vs Git Checkout -B with upstream repo**

**`git fetch upstream model-package`** — This command downloads updates to model-package branch, and saves them to upstream/model-package.

You can compare changes to the local model-package branch via `git diff model-package upstream/model-package`, and if you're happy with the changes, you can integrate them via `git pull upstream model-package`, which will apply all the changes to your local model-package branch.

**`git checkout model-package`** — This will move you from your current branch to the mentioned branch, `model-package`. All your changes in this branch will be in your local until you push to the remote branch.

**`git checkout -B model-package upstream/model-package`** — This will create a new model-package branch on the local repo that tracks the upstream model-package branch. It won't sync with your upstream remote branches until you push the changes to the remote branch. You can change remote-tracking branch (sync) at any time, with any remote, any branch, it's completely up to you.
[Click here for more information on, how to change remote tracking branch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-to-change-the-remote-a-branch-is-tracking)

*Note: Correct me If any points that I have mentioned here are incorrect.*