# Remote git parent branch was renamed, how do I update my in progress local feature branch?

Tags: git

So I have a "feature" branch, branched off of "develop". But now the remote "develop" branch has been renamed to "qa" by another developer. How do I make sure my local branches including the "feature" branch that I have in progress reflects this change?

Comment: Pull. Prune. Delete the local (obsolete) "develop" branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local `develop` branch is pointing to the remote branch name `develop`, you need to update its reference with the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/2347196 (assuming the remote is `origin`, `git branch develop --set-upstream-to origin/qa`).

In order to avoid confusion I would also suggest to rename your local `develop` branch to `qa` with the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/2347196 (`git branch -m develop qa`), but this is optional.

Other local branches such as `feature` don't need to be changed because they keep their history through hashes, not through branch names, so they don't reference `develop` by name.