# Specified wrong branch name for git push -u

Tags: git, git-push

I was working in my repository on *branch_old* but then wanted to create a new branch, lets say *branch_new*, for my local changes and finally push this new branch onto remote, so I ran

`git checkout -b branch_new`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "Some message"`

`git push -u origin branch_old`

while I meant to ultimately run `git push -u origin branch_new`.

As a return, I got

`Everything up to date`

`branch 'branch_old' set up to track 'origin/branch_old'`

Now I'm quite new to git and I don't really know if that messed something up with the setup of my original branch *branch_old*. I couldn`t find a post with the same problem, so can someone tell me if that wrong push command was harmful and if yes, how can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did nothing harmful here. You probably didn't want to push the old branch but you did - however, you can delete that branch (on the remote) if you like, and in any case it is nothing harmful in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The information of an "upstream" branch is only local information. This is not something that is pushed to the remote. You can find the information in `.git/config` inside your local repository, something like:

```
[branch "branch_old"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/branch_old
```

To change the upstream, you can run

```
git branch branch_old --set-upstream-to origin/branch_new
```

A more detailed version of this answer for older git versions etc can be found here: [How to change the remote a branch is tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878249/how-to-change-the-remote-a-branch-is-tracking)