# Git Diff and Meld on Windows

Tags: git, msysgit, git-diff, meld, difftool

Has anyone ever made Meld work with Git on Windows?
I am trying to make it work and I have no success.

I have Meld installed and when I call it from the command line with two files as parameters it diffs them well so Meld is installed correctly. However I can't make it work with Git (Git Diff). I use version `git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1` of Git.

I have tried several things:
I created a shell script, `meld.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
meld.exe "$2" "$5"
echo $2
echo $5
```

and used it from Git:

```
[diff]
    tool = meld

[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = \"D:\\meld.sh\"
```

I tried to add it as a difftool like this:

```
[diff]
    tool = meld

[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Meld\\meld\\meld.exe\"
```

or like this:

```
[diff]
    tool = meld

[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = '\"/c/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe\" $PWD/$LOCAL $PWD/$BASE $PWD/$REMOTE --output=$PWD/$MERGED'
```

But it really does not seem to work. I also tried to echo the second($2) and fifth($5) parameter from my shell script and no output. I also tried using a batch script in several ways:

```
meld.exe %2 %5
```

or

```
meld.exe %~2 %~5
```

But it really does not work... How can I pass the two versions of the file `Git` uses when diffing to Meld?
It's pretty annoying...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usually, you can find an example on Windows similar to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tacsio/898911), with meld.exe being in your `PATH`):

```
git config --global merge.tool meld
git config --global mergetool.meld.cmd 'meld.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"'

git config --global diff.tool meld
git config --global difftool.meld.cmd 'meld.exe \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"'
```

You can find more robust settings in "[Git mergetool with Meld on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14821358/6309)", but the idea remains the same.

---

The OP reports in the comments:

> For the `difftool`, your commands write the following configurations in `.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
  tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
  cmd = meld.exe \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\"
```

I changed them to:

```
[diff]
  tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
  cmd = meld.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

> and everything worked fine.

Comment: I tried your method but it does not work properly. Here how it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/KIaVb04.png. If you have any issues in understanding the paths please let me know, I hid the user name and part of the file name.

Comment: Managed to make the `difftool` work. Haven't tried the `mergetool` but chanses are that they will work the same. For the `difftool` your commands write the following configurations in `.gitconfig`:
`[diff]
 tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
 cmd = meld.exe \\\"$LOCAL\\\" \\\"$REMOTE\\\"`
I changed them to:
`[diff]
 tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
 cmd = meld.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE`
and everything worked fine. I will try with `mergetool` later but I will accept your comment :)
Thanks!

Comment: @JasonSwartz great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I tried meld as a mergetool and i used the same parameters for meld as for the difftool: `cmd = meld.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE` and worked wonderful. Otherwise it crashed probably because of the parameters.
Thanks, again!

Comment: removing the quotes on the `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` was absolutely key for me. must be like `cmd = meld.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE `

Comment: " [diff]
 tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
 cmd = \"D:\\software\\melddiff\\Meld.exe\" $LOCAL $REMOT ". Mine is like this on win7 and I got an error: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-mergetool--lib:行124: D:\software\melddiff\Meld.exe: can't find the command"

Comment: @AllenVork Strange. Could you ask a separate question, with the exact version of Git and Meld? I suppose you do have the file `D:\software\melddiff\Meld.exe`?

Comment: I solved it. I change it to "D:/software/melddiff/Meld.exe" and it works.The .gitconfig's format is ubuntu not windows.

Answer (score 7):

Or even better, if you're on a locked-down system where fooling with the path is not allowed or you just don't want to pollute your path space, you can just put in the full path to Meld.

I also prefer my current working code copy to show up on the left, so I swapped the $REMOTE and $LOCAL arguments. Also mind the conversions of \ to / and don't for get to escape the double quotes.

```
[diff]
    tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe\" $REMOTE $LOCAL
```

Answer (score 6):

For Windows 7 (or even other versions of windows), add these lines in the `.gitconfig` file.

```
[diff]
    tool = meld
[merge]
    tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld.exe
[mergetool "meld"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld.exe
```

Note that there is no need to use `"` for the path even if it includes spaces. Just remember to use forward slashes instead of backward slashes.

Comment: It works in Windows Server 2012 R2 out of the box. Easiest solution found.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 10 with latest versions of GIt and Meld.

Comment: Clean solution for both diff and merge, thanks! Minor comment, based on my experience and on all other answers posted here: the default path to Meld rather seems to be `C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld.exe`. I'll propose an edit in the answer

Comment: For meld version 3.20.3, the default installation path is `C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Meld/Meld.exe`, so the path should be `path = C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Meld/Meld.exe`

Answer (score 2):

I tried several variations of trying to set the path with `git config` to no avail. Since I want to use Meld from the Git Bash console window, what did work was to export the path to the Meld directory, restart the Bash shell and lo & behold `git difftool --tool-help` and `git mergetool --tool-help` now recognize Meld, and I can choose it as my preferred tool.

**.profile**

```
export PATH=/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Meld/:$PATH
```

**.gitconfig**

```
[merge]
    tool = meld
[diff]
    tool = meld
```

Answer (score 1):

Another tip for users invoking diff from gitk (*by right-clicking the context menu item **"External Diff"***):

The above settings may get overridden by gitk's preferences. In that case, change the tools in gitk's menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *General* → *External diff* setting.