# How do I restore the default settings or use a UI tool for git diff?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-diff, meld

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and before pushing the code, I used to run command `git diff` so that I can know what changes I made in the code.

Then someone told me, I should use meld for resolving merge confilcts.

I am not able to resolve any conflicts nor able to use git diff anymore, because meld is too complicated.
So I want to restore back the old git diff.

I am getting this error when I do `git diff`.

```
Usage: 
  meld                        Start with an empty window
  meld <file|dir>             Start a version control comparison
  meld <file> <file> [<file>] Start a 2- or 3-way file comparison
  meld <dir> <dir> [<dir>]    Start a 2- or 3-way directory comparison
  meld <file> <dir>           Start a comparison between file and dir/file

meld: error: too many arguments (wanted 0-3, got 7)
external diff died, stopping at app/Plugin/Community/Controller/CommunitiesContr
```

All I want to see is the difference of code edited by me from the original, so that I can verify the changes before pushing.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Nope. Still looking for answer.. is it possible to use git diff?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `git difftool`?

```
git difftool --tool=meld yourfile
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119867/7076798) that describes how to configure difftool to use meld as default tool.

In short:

1. Open your git configuration file (usually `~/.gitconfig` on linux)
2. and enter the following sections:

   ```
   [diff]
     tool = meld
   [difftool]
     prompt = false
   [difftool "meld"]
     cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
   ```
3. Now you can call `git difftool yourfile`

The link above also describes how to configure meld as default merge tool.