# Git - Tool that shows diff side-by-side while comparing any commits

Tags: git, github, diff

I'm moving from Bazaar to Git.

One of the main features however that I'm sorely missing is the following.

Bazaar allows you to view a commit log of a file and then select any two commits and see the diff between them side by side.

[image: Bazaar Diff]

Is there a way to achieve this in Git and/or GitHub?

Comment: Most of IDEs have this functionality, so just google how enable it in your IDE

Comment: You could use difftool. Please watch the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119867/8485203

Comment: Do you mean `git diff revision_1:file revision_2:file`?

Comment: Github's own client has this as well

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see anywhere in your examples side-by-side but rather the standard top-bottom view.