# Configuring git-gui to use meld

Tags: git, git-gui, meld

I trying to use git-gui (version 0.21.windows.2), more specifically I want to use [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) as my difftool to be launched from within git-gui.

After browsing to **Tools > Add** and I am not sure what to enter into the popup window. I found many descriptions on how to set meld as difftool for commandline, but nothing on how to do it for the git-GUI. I tried `git difftool` as name and `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe" $LOCAL $REMOTE` as command, keeping all checkboxes empty, see screenshot:

[image]

I can press **Add** which closes the popup without any warning message. A new menu entry under **Tools** is successfully created. However, if I choose now the entry **Tools > git difftool** I receive the following error message:

> Cannot import: GTK+
>
> DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Please advise!

#### References

- The official documentation is rather brief: bit https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui
- [Setting up and using Meld as your git difftool and mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119866/setting-up-and-using-meld-as-your-git-difftool-and-mergetool) describes the command line approach