# Installation and setting meld on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, meld

I have a problem installing MELD ...
At the beginning I entered the command:

- brew cask install meld

Then I entered:

- git config --global merge.tool meld

And at the end:

- git mergetool

But I got the answer:

- The merge tool meld is not available as 'meld'

I was looking for solutions but nothing helps ...

Could anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up and using Meld as your git difftool and mergetool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119866/setting-up-and-using-meld-as-your-git-difftool-and-mergetool)