# Scanning for patterns in files modified under git

Tags: git

How do you scan for patterns on changed lines within a git repo?

I'm trying to find the pattern "<<<<<<<" in all files locally modified.

To do this I thought I'd output git's diff, which should show all changed lines, and then just do a grep, like:

```
git diff --diff-filter=d origin/master | grep -B 5 -A 5 '<<<<<<<'
```

However, instead of outputting a diff, this launches my meld (on Ubuntu), my local `git difftool`. How do I stop it from launching meld and make it simply output a diff?

Comment: When I try git diff --diff-filter=d origin/master | findstr "\-" on windows it works just fine, printing lines that were removed. Maybe it's a linux configuration when executing git?

Comment: @james-braz The command that's launching meld is the `git diff...` part, not the grep part. Replacing grep with findstr results in the same behavior.

Comment: So you want to use regular git diff even though you configured 
[diff]
    tool = meld
in your .gitconfig?

Comment: There are two separate questions here once you break this down: (1) how to inspect just changed lines; (2) why does `git diff ... | ...` still run the configured difftool? The answer to (2) should be obvious now. The answer I would use for (1) is to use `git log -S` or `git log -G`.

Comment: @JamesBraz I want to use the plaintext diff functionality for this specific case without disabling my normal diff tool, yes.

Comment: @torek I want to look at local changes, even those that haven't been committed. `git log` will only show committed changes, right?

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119866/setting-up-and-using-meld-as-your-git-difftool-and-mergetool, meld should only be launched when using git difftool command (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool), not the regular git diff command.

Comment: Ah, yes, `git log` can't look at uncommitted data. And @JamesBraz's update is right, `git diff` shouldn't run the diff *tool* by default. However, if you have a diff filter defined via `.gitattributes`, that might explain it.

Comment: @JamesBraz That's what I thought too, but unfortunately, `git diff` does launch meld.