# View differences of tags with a diff tool (like meld)

Tags: git, difftool

The question is simple - how is it possible to view the difference between two tags from a project, but with the power of a GUI, not only the the console?

There is a lot of questions about view diff between commits, branches. Also helpful is diff between tags. Also the questions have a lot of old answers with the hints to external tools to add the possibility to use GUI tools to the diff command. Since git 1.7.11 is that not necessary, since this version has git the possibility `difftool` include.

Answer (score 2):

Since version of git 1.7.11 is it possible to use [`git difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) with a external tool, that get your UI for your requirements.

#### Configuation

To set the tool what you like, use the command below to set it it globally in your git configuration. in this example I set the tool [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) as default tool.

`git config --global diff.tool meld`.

**For windows** users is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238883/git-diff-and-meld-on-windows) and his answer really helpful.

#### Diff two tags

After this step, you can use Meld for view different tags, branches, commits. As example to view two different tags of an repository use the command.

```
git difftool tag1 tag2
```

#### Result

Now, the console list for each file the possibility to view the diff in the external tool with the UI. Also here a example of the return message for a diff in the `readme.md` file.

```
Viewing (2/30): 'README.md'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]:
```

If you use the `Y` to allow to start the tool you get the diff in Meld.

#### More about `difftool`

This diff is also possible for branches, commits or single file. Much more options, possibilities, listed in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks