# Repository already exists - or not?

Tags: git, github

I must admit that I'm totally confused about initialising Git - though it's not for the first time really.

I first downloaded original Git bash and made a repository *something* at `C:\xampp\htdocs\something`. At the same time, I created *something* repository under my profile. I thought they might link together then (after I log in) - such naivity was soon punished.

Then I realised that this Git bash really doesn't like me, so I downloaded standard "Git for windows".
I deleted `.git` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\something`, and I deleted the online version of the repository. I also looked at `Documents\GitHub\` for `something` folder, but it's not there.

But well, sounds like I didn't delete it enough - have a look:
[image: repository already exists]
So where else does Git store data about existing repos? Will I have to pick different name just because of this?
Can I list the repositories to see why it happens?

#### Initialising repo through console (success)

Possible workaround is using the Git shell console:

`cd C:\xampp\htdocs\something`
`git init`
`Initialized empty Git repository in C:/xampp/htdocs/rimedit/.git/`

#### Pushing with GUI application (failed)

But using console is a workaround, not an answer. Also I still can't push because of this:
[image: Failed to push]

#### Pushing with console (failed too)

To piss me of as much as possible, this is what console throws upon pushing:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Darker/rimedit.git/' not found
```

Note that the error is the exact opposite to the one I get with the GUI application.

#### Deleting cache

Git stores some cached data and account information at `%APPDATA%\GitHub\` ([thanks Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21098924/607407)). Deleting the cache did not solve the problem - it appears that it might be server-sided.

### Finally a solution (not an answer)

The *`Repository not found.`* in the console was simply fixed by creating the repository on the server once again. After this, I'd get this for push:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Darker/rimedit.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I wanted to pull, but again an error:

```
 * [new branch]      master     -> git/master
You asked to pull from the remote 'git', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
```

So, after all, I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847136/607407). I edited my config to look like this:

```
[remote "git"]
  url = https://github.com/<account name>/<repo name>.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/git/*

[branch "master"]
  remote = git
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

After this, all I needed was to `pull` the `readme.md` and then `push` all my data.

Comment: I also suspect that there is a problem on the server. At this point you may want to [contact GitHub support](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: I did contact them. I'm waiting for reply already. I was in touch with them for a while - but they don't know anything for sure, so this might be a bug. The `git init` solution came from github support.

Answer (score 0):

`.git` is the only directory with git metadata. So if specific directory is the child directory of some directory that have `.git` directory, it is some kind of **inside** a git repository.

Maybe there is some "Git for Windows" metadata that made it possible to recognize previously existing repository. Or you still have `.git` directory with git metadata files.

Comment: No `.git` folders exist in any searchable folder in whole `C:` (I searched carefully). I have strong suspition that git GUI application has it cached somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `Documents\GitHub\` for a directory called `something`. Delete that and you should be on your way.

GitHub for Windows also saves information in `%APPDATA%\GitHub\`, but this does not appear to be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Chris, I've stated that I looked in the document and the folder wasn't there. It's the last sentence of the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: Have you also tried deleting the folder in `%APPDATA%`? I wasn't able to reproduce your problem, but the cache files in there may be relevant.

Comment: I will try to do that, right now I'm checking what effect that may have. I guess that aside from criticising, I should've told you, that the second part of your answer seems promising.

Comment: Deleting cache did not help.

Answer (score 0):

git push /f will overide the repositary

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32326883)