# Working with multiple repositories from different servers

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-remote

I have two repositories: One in github and another on Bitbucket.
I'm confused. Using `git Bash` how may I select which remote repository I want to work with ? Is there an easy way to switch between them ? ( I already have my project on remote server).

**Update**

I could 'add' two repositories with the following command:

```
git add remote Repository_URL
```

Now if I do

```
git remote -v
```

It shows me both repositories and its URLs.

Now I need to know how to select one of them to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the remote name in a specific git command. For example, if they were called `github` and `bitbucket`:

```
git pull github master
git pull bitbucket master

git fetch bitbucket

git push github master
```

etc.

You can also [specify a per-branch default remote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847136/1445366) in your config file if you like.