# How to git pull a specific branch on my development remote server?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to create a Local -> Development -> Production environment with the help of Git(hub). But I cannot find the right way to do this.

**These are the levels:**

1. Local development repository with a master, develop and feature branches.
2. Github repository with master, develop and feature branches.
3. Test remote server https://test.website.com/
4. Production server https://website.com/

**This is the workflow I have in mind:**

1) I make my changes locally, first in `feature` branches.

2) Merge `feature` branch with `develop` branch.

3) Push to Github repository.

4) Pull the `develop` branch to my test remote server. Test if everything is ok.

```
// Development server
ssh username@[IP_ADDRESS]
cd /to/my/git/folder
git pull https://www.github.com/user/repo
```

5) Merge my develop branch into `master`.

6) Pull my `master` branch on my production remote server.

```
// Production server    
ssh username@[IP_ADDRESS] 
cd /to/my/git/folder
git pull https://www.github.com/user/repo
```

**The Problem**

The problem I am facing is that when I `git pull` my repo on the development server I only get my `master` branch. But I want my `develop` branch on my development server and my `master` branch on my production server.

Is this even an efficient workflow or do I need to design it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the development server you can do `git pull && git checkout <development-branch-name>`
It will update the git repo with the changes and switch the repo to use the development branch.

Take a look at this question to know how to configure your `.gitconfig` file to track the remote branch - [Git: which is the default configured remote for branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847101/git-which-is-the-default-configured-remote-for-branch#4849945)

Regarding the workflow, that is how things are done in places that I have worked. So, I guess it seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will checkout the link for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
> ssh username@[IP_ADDRESS] 
> cd /to/my/git/folder 
> git init
> git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
> git pull origin develop
```

I had to set my remote so I was able to pull the right develop branch.