# Difference between git checkout --track origin/branch and git checkout -b branch origin/branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-checkout

Does anybody know the difference between these two commands to switch and track a remote branch?

```
git checkout -b branch origin/branch
git checkout --track origin/branch
```

I think both keep track of the remote branch so I can push my changes to the branch on origin, right?

Are there any practical differences?

Answer (score 425, accepted):

The two commands have the same effect ([thanks to Robert Siemer’s answer for pointing it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784240/825924)).

The practical difference comes when using a local branch named *differently*:

- `git checkout -b mybranch origin/abranch` will create `mybranch` and track `origin/abranch`
- `git checkout --track origin/abranch` will only create '`abranch`', not a branch with a different name.

(That is, [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002239/difference-between-git-checkout-track-origin-branch-and-git-checkout-b-branch/10002469#comment82673579_10002469) by [Sebastian Graf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388010/sebastian-graf), if the local branch did *not* exist already.
If it did, you would need `git checkout -B abranch origin/abranch`)

---

Note: with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), that would use the **[new command `git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)**:

```
git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

> If the branch exists in multiple remotes and one of them is named by the `checkout.defaultRemote` configuration variable, we'll use that one for the purposes of disambiguation, even if the `<branch>` isn't unique across all remotes.
>   Set it to e.g. `checkout.defaultRemote=origin` to always checkout remote branches from there if `<branch>` is ambiguous but exists on the 'origin' remote.

Here, '`-c`' is the new '`-b`'.

---

First, some background: **Tracking** means that a local branch has its upstream set to a remote branch:

```
# git config branch.<branch-name>.remote origin
# git config branch.<branch-name>.merge refs/heads/branch
```

---

`git checkout -b branch origin/branch` will:

- create/reset `branch` to the point referenced by `origin/branch`.
- create the branch `branch` (with [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)) and track the remote tracking branch `origin/branch`.

> **When a local branch is started off a remote-tracking branch, Git sets up the branch (specifically the `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` configuration entries)** so that `git pull` will appropriately merge from the remote-tracking branch.
>   This behavior may be changed via the global `branch.autosetupmerge` configuration flag. That setting can be overridden by using the `--track` and `--no-track` options, and changed later using git branch `--set-upstream-to`.

---

And `git checkout --track origin/branch` will do the same as [`git branch --set-upstream-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--ultupstreamgt)):

```
 # or, since 1.7.0
 git branch --set-upstream upstream/branch branch
 # or, since 1.8.0 (October 2012)
 git branch --set-upstream-to upstream/branch branch
 # the short version remains the same:
 git branch -u upstream/branch branch
```

It would also set the upstream for '`branch`'.

(Note: git1.8.0 will deprecate `git branch --set-upstream` and replace it with `git branch -u|--set-upstream-to`: see [git1.8.0-rc1 announce](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/ANNOUNCE-Git-v1-8-0-rc1-tc7568792.html))

---

Having an upstream branch registered for a local branch will:

- tell git to **show the relationship between the two branches in `git status` and `git branch -v`**.
- directs **`git pull` *without arguments* to pull from the upstream when the new branch is checked out**.

See "[How do you make an existing git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)" for more.

Comment: @VonC I been looking for that little detail you happened to mention as extra information. In my case, I was curious why I had some my branches allow me to `git pull`, whereas some branches would ask for a remote branch to pull from. It turns out that if you, in your first-time, are checking out a remote branch that your peer created, git goes on and adds `branch.<BNAME>.remote=origin` to the local gitconfig. Which then allows you to issue `git pull`. However, if you are the one creating the branch `git checkout -b BNAME`, then git -of course- does not know. So you should specify its remote.

Comment: @batilc "It turns out that if you, in your first-time, are checking out a remote branch that your peer created,"; yes, reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout, I see: "`If <branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to `$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`"

Comment: @VonC I found a better configuration for this. setting up `branch.autoSetupMerge` to `always` simply performs what we are talking about. This setting defaults to `true`, which means the tracking will be performed only when checking out a remote branch. `true` does not setup tracking for locally created branches.

Comment: @batilc I agree. I tend to not use always, as I prefer to explicitly set tracking, but in your case, that should be the right setting.

Comment: @VonC I respect that, and agree on that you need to know what you are about to forego when performing these configurations. But I'd like to ask this: What happens if you checkout a branch with `--track` option while having this `autosetupmerge` setting on? My guess would be that your explicit configuration should be overriding the `autosetupmerge` option. Just asking if you have tried it already

Comment: @batilc I haven't tried it. I suppose indeed the explict config should prevail.

Comment: "git branch --set-upstream-to branch upstream/branch"
is not the correct syntax. it should be:
"git branch --set-upstream-to upstream/branch branch"

Answer (score 50):

**There is no difference at all!**

1) `git checkout -b branch origin/branch`

If there is no `--track` and no `--no-track`, `--track` is assumed as default. The default can be changed with the setting `branch.autosetupmerge`.

In effect, 1) behaves like `git checkout -b branch --track origin/branch`.

2) `git checkout --track origin/branch`

“As a convenience”, `--track` without `-b` implies `-b` and the argument to `-b` is guessed to be “branch”. The guessing is driven by the configuration variable `remote.origin.fetch`.

In effect, 2) behaves like `git checkout -b branch --track origin/branch`.

**As you can see: no difference.**

But it gets even better:

3) `git checkout branch`

is also equivalent to `git checkout -b branch --track origin/branch` if “branch” does not exist yet but “origin/branch” does<sup>1</sup>.

---

All three commands set the “upstream” of “branch” to be “origin/branch” (or they fail).

Upstream is used as reference point of argument-less `git status`, `git push`, `git merge` and thus `git pull` (if configured like that (which is the default or almost the default)).

E.g. `git status` tells you how far behind or ahead you are of upstream, if one is configured.

`git push` is configured to push the current branch upstream by default<sup>2</sup> since git 2.0.

<sup><sup>1</sup> ...and if “origin” is the only remote having “branch”</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> the default (named “simple”) *also* enforces for both branch names to be equal</sup>

Comment: This is a great answer because it explains many implicit arguments in git commands used commonly by many of us at the command line wiith or without a though of all the implicit assumptions that git makes for us, based on "default" configuration.

Comment: @Mikef ...neither can 3) nor any other command line I mention.

Answer (score 6):

[The book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches) seems to indicate that those commands yield the same effect:

> The simple case is the example you just saw, running git checkout -b
>   [branch] [remotename]/[branch]. If you have Git version 1.6.2 or
>   later, you can also use the --track shorthand:

```
$ git checkout --track origin/serverfix 
Branch serverfix set up to track remote branch serverfix from origin. 
Switched to a new branch 'serverfix'
```

> To set up a local branch with a different name than the
>   remote branch, you can easily use the first version with a different
>   local branch name:

```
$ git checkout -b sf origin/serverfix
```

That's particularly handy when your bash or oh-my-zsh git completions are able to pull the `origin/serverfix` name for you - just append `--track` (or `-t`) and you are on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new branch with this command

```
git checkout --track origin/branch
```

if you have changes that are not staged.

Here is example:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   src/App.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

// TRY TO CREATE:

$ git checkout --track origin/new-branch
fatal: 'origin/new-branch' is not a commit and a branch 'new-branch' cannot be created from it
```

However you can easily create a new branch with un-staged changes with `git checkout -b` command:

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
Switched to a new branch 'new-branch'
M       src/App.js
```

Comment: keep in mind that both of the commands in the questions are for tracking an existing remote branch (`origin/branch`)

Comment: @Green The test you do is with `origin/new-branch` instead of `origin/branch`. Are you aware of that?