# How to update my fork to have the same branches and tags as the original repository on github?

Tags: git, github

When you fork a repository on github your forked repo contains all branches and tags.

Over time these branches and tags gets outdated.

How does one as easy it is with fork make sure your fork has all branches and tags without having to reclone ?

i.e. a git magicpull --rebase upstream/* myremote/*

which would fetch all the branches and tags in upstream and make sure the same are present in myremote.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This assumes your "upstream" remote is named "origin" and you have your custom fork under your username (i.e. "maxandersen")

When you have your clone run the following one-liner (refresh of [Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches/6300386#6300386) :

```
remote=origin ; for brname in `git branch -r | grep origin | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | sed -e 's/^[^\/]*\///'`; do git branch --track $brname  $remote/$brname ; done
```

This will setup tracking branches for all the branches found in the remote named 'origin'.
If you already have a checkout with this branchname it will not change anything except ensure the tracking is in place.

(Optional) Now ensure all your branches are uptodate (useful if you have already branches checked out):

```
git pull --rebase --all
```

Now with all branches setup for tracking and uptodate push branches *and* tags to your remote (replace 'maxandersen' with your remote name):

```
git push --all maxandersen
git push --tags maxandersen
```

After this your fork is in sync.

The following script does all this including asking for confirmation:

```
## Checkout all branches from remote as tracking branches. Based on    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches/6300386#6300386

UPSTREAM=$1
MYREPO=$2

usage() {
   echo "Usage:"
   echo "$0 <upstream-remote> <target-remote>"
   echo ""
   echo "Example which ensures remote named 'maxandersen' have all the same branches and tags as 'origin'"
   echo "$0 origin maxandersen"
   exit 1
}

if [ -z "$UPSTREAM" ]
then
 echo Missing upstream remote name.
 usage
fi

if [ -z "$MYREPO" ]
then
 echo Missing target remote name. 
 usage
fi

read -p "1. This will setup '$MYREPO' to track all branches in '$UPSTREAM' - Are you sure ?" -n 1 -r

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
 for brname in `git branch -r | grep "$UPSTREAM" | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | sed -e 's/.*\///g'`; do git branch --track $brname  $UPSTREAM/$brname ; done
fi

read -p "2. This will push all local branches and tags into '$MYREPO' - Are you sure ?" -n 1 -r

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
 git push --all $MYREPO
 git push --tags $MYREPO
fi
```

Save it as 'updateallbranchestags.sh' and execute it with:

```
sh updateallbranches.sh origin maxandersen
```

And all branches/tags from 'origin' will be made available in remote named 'maxandersen'

Comment: Sound a concrete implementation of my answer. +1

Comment: Yes, note that I also move to use --track instead of --set-upstream to get rid of annoying deprecation warning + I used sed instead of awk to make the oneliner even shorter :) Thus thank you for the hints!

Comment: I would not recommend --track for reason explained in my one-liner answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309 (updated): you should use `--set-upstream-to` (or `-u`), as explain in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309

Comment: thanks - didn't realize that subtle difference. answer updated.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know `--set-upstream-to` didn't work in this case. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: very nice, I would adjust the sed expression to avoid stripping away parts of branch names with slashes in: `'s/^[^\/]*\///'`

Comment: Any way to do this in powershell?

Answer (score 22):

You would still need a local clone, which would:

- fetch and update all the upstream branches into local branches (git fetch upstream, with upstream being a reference to the original repo you have forked)
  See "[How do I clone all remote branches with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699/6309)" for more on having all remote branches as local branches.
  I use this [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches/6300386#6300386) from the question "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379081/6309)".
  See also "[What is the difference between `origin` and `upstream` in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309)"

[image: upstream and fork]

- `git push --all origin` (origin being your fork):  that supposes that:

  - you have all the local branches tracking all the upstream branches (see previous step).
    Otherwise, you would push only one local branch by default, since a clone would create only one local branch (the default one)
  - you haven't pushed commits of your own on those branches.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly push the remote refs.
Obviously this doesn't take into account changes in the fork, But it still answers the question. And if the changes are limited then you can easily merge/rebase them using your local branches.

```
git push -f origin refs/remotes/upstream/*:refs/heads/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I have translated the Bash script given in the excellent answer by [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71208/max-rydahl-andersen) into Batch script, just in case you need this on Windows. The only gotcha is that, to run this on Windows, you need to have grep and sed tools available in your preferred terminal application (I personally use [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/) and Windows Terminal).

```
@echo off

set UPSTREAM=%~1
set MYREPO=%~2

if "%UPSTREAM%" == "" (
    echo Missing upstream remote name.
    goto :usage
)

if "%MYREPO%" == "" (
    echo Missing target remote name.
    goto :usage
)

set /p REPLY="Setup '%MYREPO%' to track all branches in '%UPSTREAM%' [y/n]? "

set "_YES=0"
if "%REPLY%" == "y" set "_YES=1"
if "%REPLY%" == "Y" set "_YES=1"
if %_YES% equ 1 (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%G in ('git branch -r ^| grep %UPSTREAM% ^| grep -v master ^| grep -v HEAD ^| sed -e "s/.*\///g"') do (
        git branch --track %%G %UPSTREAM%/%%G
    )
)

set /p REPLY="Push all local branches in '%MYREPO%' [y/n]? "

set "_YES=0"
if "%REPLY%" == "y" set "_YES=1"
if "%REPLY%" == "Y" set "_YES=1"
if %_YES% equ 1 (
    git pull --rebase --all
    git push --all %MYREPO%
    git push --tags %MYREPO%
)

exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%

:usage
echo Usage:
echo %~0 upstream-remote target-remote
echo Example which ensures remote named 'origin' have all the same branches and tags as 'upstream'
echo %~0 upstream origin
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, when you need to sync repositories, a smart way is to use the `gh` tool provided by github :

- Official github repository : https://github.com/cli/cli.git
- Official GitHub Cli Docs : https://cli.github.com/manual/
- Sync repositories with GitHub Cli : https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_sync

Using `gh repo sync` inside a git safe directory is enough since some times, unless there are something to merge (locally or remote), of course, and if it is the case, official docs examples are self explanatory :

## Sync local repository from remote parent

$ gh repo sync

## Sync local repository from remote parent on specific branch

$ gh repo sync --branch v1

## Sync remote fork from its parent

$ gh repo sync owner/cli-fork

## Sync remote repository from another remote repository

$ gh repo sync owner/repo --source owner2/repo2

Comment: This answer could be usefull too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65401892/390462