# GIT fetch from another repo -- how to push correct tags

Tags: git, git-tag, git-fetch

I have a repo **B** which "branched" from another some time ago. However, I still need to apply some commits from its "father" repo **A** from time to time. So, in repo **B** I did:

```
git remote add repoA git@someurl.git
git fetch repoA
```

Now, in repo **B** I can, for example, `cherry pick` some of the things that keep on happening on repo **A**...

However, when I do `git push --tags` he tries to push to repo **B** all of its tags plus the tags from repo **A**.

1. What is the correct process to push only the tags belonging to repo **B** to *origin*?
2. In general, am I working correctly with Git for this particular case, when I still to need merge some things from a "long gone" father into some repo? Am I risking to push "garbage" into the repo **B**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ([git 1.8.3+, May 2013](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L155-L156)):

```
git push --follow-tags
```

That should push only the commits and tags from your current branch in one command ([if your push policy is set to `simple`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309))

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 2, *my opinion* is that it is more intuitive and straight forward to keep the legacy code on a branch. Generally speaking, different systems are kept in different repos and an old release track that is only maintained to a certain extent is kept on a branch in the one repo containing your system. But again, that is *my opinion* and not a fact :)

Comment: I agree with what you said. However, in this case, it's not quite legacy code, but something that has a common code base but which development follows its own path, and from which I can make no assumptions... so, in fact, the first repo continues to be developed and I just want to be able to "cherry pick" some specific changes, from time to time...