# How to get files from another branch on different PC

Tags: git

Basically, on one PC I created a branch, let's say `new_branch` and made some changes there. Now I want to get the whole repository from that branch on a different PC.

The problem is that when I'm using:

```
git checkout new_branch
```

I get the message that the new_branch does not exist. And by default I'm on master.

How can I do that?

Comment: what does `git branch -r` report?

Answer (score 1):

Once cloned on the new PC, you can do a:

```
git checkout -b new_branch origin/new_branch
# or better
git checkout --track origin/new_branch
```

By default, a clone checks out the master branch, and creates remote tracking branches in the `remotes/origin` namespace: you you see all those remote tracking branches with `git branch -r`.

See more with "[Difference between `git checkout --track origin/branch` and `git checkout -b branch origin/branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309)".

If you use the `--track` option, your local branch will have the remote tracking branch has its **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)**.
By default, a simple `git push` would push that local branch on the same branch of the origin repo.

Comment: `git checkout new_branch` if origin/new_branch exists has automatically created the local branch and setup tracking for as far back as my Git memory goes

Comment: @AndrewC indeed. Maybe that clone doesn't have the remote tracking branches, and needs a git fetch to fully list them.