# GIT: fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I was pushing my master branch to my GIT repo and go this error

```
  fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
```

On the advice of a stack question I typed

```
  git remote -v
```

and got

```
  heroku    https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-cove-8372.git (fetch)
  heroku    https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-cove-8372.git (push)
  origin    https://github.com/SimonWalsh1000/breathe.git (fetch)
  origin    https://github.com/SimonWalsh1000/breathe.git (push)
```

I then typed

```
   simonalice$ git push -u origin master
```

And it worked but said

```
   Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

I am very new to GIT and I am not fully sure what has happened. I would be very grateful if someone could explain this sequence to me. I haven't been able to get clear answers. Is my master branch now, the master branch in GIT or is it some clone?

Many thanks

Comment: My guess is that you initially ran `git push master`, which Git interprets as a request to push the current branch to a remote named `master`, rather than request to push the branch `master` to its default remote.

Comment: I think you are right. How would I get everything back the way it should be. Based upon the last response above - Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin - does this mean the master on my computer and in GIT are the same thing? If not, how can I remedy this?

Comment: No, it just means that from now on (assuming `master` is checked out), that `git push` will behave like `git push origin master`. That is, unless you specify a different remote, the local branch `master` will be pushed to `origin`. You can always override it if you like, e.g., `git push heroku` to push to `heroku` instead of `origin`. I don't think there's anything you need to fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And it worked but said

Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

Do a git config --local -l

You will see that the local branch master is set to track the [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) `origin/master`

See "[Difference between `git checkout --track origin/branch` and `git checkout -b branch origin/branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309)".

It would be like you did:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/branch
```

The *first* push needs that upstream information: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

Comment: Helped a lot (in particular your link)

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error while doing `git pull <branch>`, and I fixed it by changing that to `git pull origin <branch>`.