# How to avoid detached headstate in git?

Tags: git

I am trying to get a remote branch and track it but when I do:

```
git checkout remotes/mybranch
```

When I do git branch -a it displays remotes/mybranch in the red color?
I get an error:

```
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
```

How can I checkout to this mybranch locally and track it? How can I avoid the detached HEAD state?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what do I do next time to avoid this detached state?

See "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)"

You simply have to checkout a local named branched, as opposed to a remote tracking one (like `origin/mybranch`).
The remote tracking branch `origin/mybranch` isn't made to record commits, but only to track the commits fetched from the upstream repo.

To avoid that:

```
git checkout -b abranch origin/abranch
```

Or rather, since [Git 2.23 (Q3 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)), using [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git switch abranch
```

That will will create the local branch "`abranch`" and track `origin/abranch`.

See "[Difference between `git checkout --track origin/branch` and `git checkout -b branch origin/branc`h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309)"

Answer (score 0):

Make a temporary branch then point master to it to reconcile with the detached HEAD like so:

```
git checkout -b temporary_branch
git branch -f master temporary_branch
git checkout master
```

Then you can do what you are trying to do:

```
git checkout remotes/mybranch
```

Comment: what do I do next time to avoid this detached state?

Comment: Were you trying to do git rebase? If not, you likely switched to a previous commit and so detached your HEAD. This guy explains it pretty well I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head

Answer (score 0):

To create a new tracking branch, you can just do this:

```
git checkout mybranch
```

This will automatically create a local tracking branch and check it out.  It will fail if there are multiple remotes which have a branch named `mybranch`.

You can rescue work you've done in detached head, but if you haven't done any work in the detached HEAD it is easier just to run the above command.

Comment: Getting the same error when I do :git checkout mybranch

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid the detached HEAD state?

Detached HEAD happens when your HEAD points to a specific commit instead to a branch:

[image]

By using `git checkout` with a specific hash, you can decide either to point to a specific commit or to a branch.

The command `git switch` (added in Git v2.23) was added to only work at branch level (and not at commit level), so a good way to avoid detached heads, is to use `git switch` instead of `git checkout` to switch between branches, so this will prevent you to make your HEAD point to a commit unintentionally.

Comment: Yes, I explained last year why `git switch` was better, in "[Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)"