# git push to remote repo, but seems nothing is uploaded on repo

Tags: git

I'm on mac and trying "git push" to a local repo simulator directory:

```
mkdir ~/gitremote
cd ~/gitremote
git init --bare
```

Then in another directory:

```
git clone /Users/trosky/gitremote
vi readme (add one line)
git add .
git commit -m "1st file"
git push -u origin master

Counting objects: 2, done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 211 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /Users/trosky/gitremote/
   c0a3498..ff5511b  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Everything seems OK. But under ~/gitremote:

```
$ls
HEAD        config      hooks       objects
branches    description info        refs
```

Seems the "readme" file is not uploaded at all.
I tried this test several times, always same issue. What happen when I can successfully git push to master, while the "remote" repo doesn't have anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push new file to a bare repo failed: "error: src refspec master does not match any." Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326402/git-push-new-file-to-a-bare-repo-failed-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-mat)

Comment: You're probably not pushing where you think...by the way, what is the reason for the bare repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git doesn't push files.  For that matter, repositories don't store files either—not directly, anyway (but see the next few paragraphs).  Repositories store *commits*, and git pushes commits.

The whole point of a `--bare` clone is to avoid having any files, so that there are no files to get in the way of the commits.  If you did have files there, they could prevent updating commits.

You might wonder: what good is a system that has no files?  Indeed, it would be no good at all, so repositories store commits, and each commit represents a *snapshot* of an entire directory-tree full of files.  You can then direct Git to extract *any* commit from the set of all commits saved in the repository.

Now, if and when you *do* direct Git to extract some commit—to make a directory full of every file that was saved in that particular commit—you need to give Git a place to *put* those files.  A normal, non-`--bare` repository has one distinguished place for this, called a *work-tree* (or sometimes *working-tree* or similar).  This work-tree lets you view all the files, change them, add new files, remove files, and then make a *new* commit from the result.

In other words, the work-tree is where you do your work.

If you're doing your work in your work-tree, and *someone else* pushes a commit *to* your repository, and that new commit is used to replace your work-tree with *their* committed tree, what happens to all of *your* work?  It would all be lost!  So Git generally refuses a push to your repository when your repository has a work-tree.<sup>1</sup>

Hence, Git provides the *bare* repository.  A bare repository is one with no work-tree.  With no work-tree, no one can do work in it, so push won't lose work.  It thus serves as a place you can always push to safely.  That's *all*, but that's pretty important.

If you want to see the commits (and their files) that were pushed to the bare repository, you can make a non-bare clone, and *fetch* from the pushed-to repository, into the non-bare clone, and then *check out* the commit in question.  This will replace your work with their work<sup>2</sup>—but since *you* said "do it now" you must mean that, rather than having your work rudely overwritten by their work just because they happened to push now.

As implied by the footnotes, there are lots of caveats and adjustments to this, but that's the basic setup.  A bare clone is purely for pushing into, and non-bare clones are where you do your work.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, it's only when pushing to the *current branch*, and even then it's controllable.

<sup>2</sup>The usual `git checkout` also tries to make sure you don't lose any of your own work that you have not saved.  You can tell it to "force" overwrite your own work, or use `git reset --hard` to discard your own work first, and there are plenty of complicated edge cases here, but Git generally treats all *committed data* as permanent and indelible.  Work-tree data is much less so.

Answer (score 2):

Your commit has been recorded successfully in the `gitremote` repository. Try to clone again the repo and you will see the "1st file" commit.