# what does this command git checkout -b master origin/master do?

Tags: git, github

Till now what I know from my previous usages is that,

```
git checkout -b branchName
```

creates a new branch and switches the branch to branchName

the new component origin/master  is the part I have got no clue about.

Note: while solving a merge conflict gitHub suggested the following

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

Can anyone explain what is the role of this argument & what '/' does there?

Comment: Do you know that `origin` is what Git calls a *remote*, and that `origin/*` are *remote-tracking names*? If not, start with these. The `/` itself is not particularly special, but any `origin/...` name should refer to one of these "remote-tracking" names, which exist because you `git fetch` or `git pull` from a *remote* that you call `origin`.

Answer (score 1):

it simply separate between the **remote** (the repo) to the branch name

```
git checkout -b <branch> <remote>/<branch>
```

it sets the upstream of the new branch, without using this option e.g

```
git checkout -b <branch>
```

the branch is only created locally without upstream attached at the server 
you can find more info here
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: @abdul-wahab not to duplicate answers, I refer you to a great thread the deal with this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream

Comment: he didn't ask about upstream... I answered what he asked and I assume that knowing basic git he knows what upstream is (a few pushes will do it) maybe I should explain also what is git...

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, on your remote git repository (named `origin`), you have a branch `rbranch`, then:

`git checkout -b lbranch origin/rbranch`

will create `lbranch` and track `origin/rbranch`. i.e.

1. Create the `lbranch` branch (if not already created) and track the
   remote tracking branch `origin/rbranch`.
2. Or reset `lbranch` (if
   already created) to the point referenced by `origin/rbranch`.

Since `master` is the default branch and already tracks `origin/master`, the below command:

`git checkout -b master origin/master`

will checkout `master`. And will reset the local `master` branch to the same head remote branch in on (if they were on different heads).

---

**Tracking** means that a local branch has its upstream set to a remote branch. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002239/difference-between-git-checkout-track-origin-branch-and-git-checkout-b-branch).

**Upstream** means communication from local to remote. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream).